How to extract values based on column names and put it in another column in polars?
I would like to fill a value in a column based on another columns' name, in the Polars library from python (I obtained the following DF by exploding my variables' column names):
Input:
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┘
""")

Expected output:
shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  ┆ 2     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   ┆ 3     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       ┆ 4     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  ┆ 1     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   ┆ 5     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       ┆ 10    │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘

I have tried:
df = df.with_columns(value = pl.col(f"{pl.col.variable}"))

But that does not work because polars perceives the argument as a function (?). Does anyone know how to do this?
Note: I have also tried to transpose the dataframe, which, not only was that computationally expensive, also did not work! Because it would transpose the DF into a 5-rows-long DF. What I need is a (Name * Number of Variables)-rows-long DF.
That is, for example, I have 3 different names (say, Apple, Banana, and Dragonfruit), and I have 3 variables (Average, Median, Q1), then my DF should be 9-rows-long!

You can use

when/then() to check whether the value of the column Variable is the same as the column name.
coalesce() to choose first non-empty result.

df.with_columns(
    value = pl.coalesce(
        pl.when(pl.col.Variable == col).then(pl.col(col))
        for col in df["Variable"].unique()
    )
)

┌────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  ┆ 2     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   ┆ 3     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       ┆ 4     │
│ Banana ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  ┆ 3     │
│ Banana ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   ┆ 5     │
│ Banana ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       ┆ 10    │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘


You can leverage this functionality from polars.when() and polars.then() with a mapping.
For instance,
variable_columns = ["Q1", "Average", "Median"]

expressions = [
    pl.when(pl.col("Variable") == col_name).then(pl.col(col_name))
    for col_name in variable_columns
]

combined_expr = pl.fold(
    acc=pl.lit(None),
    function=lambda acc, x: pl.coalesce(acc, x),
    exprs=expressions
)

df = df.with_columns(combined_expr.alias("Value"))


seems that this one gives me an error of 'Series object has no attribute or_' because somehow the acc is a series?

perhaps, if it's not too troublesome, can you please explain what the 'fold' method does? I've read the documentation, and it seems that it is used to do horizontal computing (row-wise operations); are you trying to iterate along each variable columns with the lambda function? What does acc and x represent then (?)

sorry my bad. The idea is similar to accepted answer. we should use coalesce as fn in fold.

You can unpivot + join with a temporary index:
df.with_row_index().join(
   df.with_row_index().unpivot(index="index", variable_name="Variable"),
   on=["index", "Variable"],
   how="left"
)

shape: (6, 7)
┌───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  ┆ 2     │
│ 1     ┆ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   ┆ 3     │
│ 2     ┆ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       ┆ 4     │
│ 3     ┆ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  ┆ 1     │
│ 4     ┆ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   ┆ 5     │
│ 5     ┆ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       ┆ 10    │
└───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘


Unfortunately it's not possible to get column value by variable in another column directly, but if we convert target columns into list and then get element by index.

pl.exclude to exclude columns we dont' need.
pl.concat_list() to create a list from target columns.
pl.Expr.replace() to convert Variable column to list index.
pl.Expr.list.get() to get the value by index.

cols = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(c for c in df.schema if c not in ("Name", "Variable"))}
# create a dictionary {'Average': 0, 'Median': 1, 'Q1': 2}

df.with_columns(
    value = pl.concat_list(cs.exclude("Name","Variable")).list.get(
        pl.col.Variable.replace(cols)
    )
)

shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  ┆ 2     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   ┆ 3     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       ┆ 4     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  ┆ 1     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   ┆ 5     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       ┆ 10    │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘


Another possible way of doing it would be to create a column using:

pl.DataFrame.with_row_index() so we have an index to keep original order later.
pl.DataFrame.unpivot() to convert it from wide format to long.
pl.DataFrame.filter() to remove rows where condition doesn't match
pl.DataFrame.sort() to return back to original order.
pl.exclude here to exclude Name column so we don't have unnecessary data in the long DataFrame.

(
    df.select(pl.exclude("Name"))
    .with_row_index()
    .unpivot(index=["index", "Variable"], variable_name="Variable2")
    .filter(pl.col.Variable == pl.col.Variable2)
    .sort("index")
)

┌───────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ Variable ┆ Variable2 ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str      ┆ str       ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ Average  ┆ Average   ┆ 2     │
│ 1     ┆ Median   ┆ Median    ┆ 3     │
│ 2     ┆ Q1       ┆ Q1        ┆ 4     │
│ 3     ┆ Average  ┆ Average   ┆ 1     │
│ 4     ┆ Median   ┆ Median    ┆ 5     │
│ 5     ┆ Q1       ┆ Q1        ┆ 10    │
└───────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┘

And now we can use

pl.concat() to concatenate it with original DataFrame

pl.concat([
    df,
    (
        df.select(cs.exclude("Name"))
        .with_row_index()
        .unpivot(index=["index", "Variable"], variable_name="Variable2")
        .filter(pl.col.Variable == pl.col.Variable2)
        .sort("index")
        .select("value")
    )
], how="horizontal")

shape: (6, 6)
┌────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ Name   ┆ Average ┆ Median ┆ Q1  ┆ Variable ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Average  ┆ 2     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Median   ┆ 3     │
│ Apple  ┆ 2       ┆ 3      ┆ 4   ┆ Q1       ┆ 4     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Average  ┆ 1     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Median   ┆ 5     │
│ Banana ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 10  ┆ Q1       ┆ 10    │
└────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴───────┘

